# Angular 6 @input() set() is not working. Is there a way to make it work?

Tags: angular, input, angular6

I created a component which will render buttons dynamically based on a JSON
which accepts few inputs like disable and color and size:

Now in the `app-dynamic-form-buttons` component I'm receiving the input like this:

```
@Input('butnDisabled')
  set butnDisabled(value: any) {
    this.disable = value;
  }
```

and assigning to a local variable.

This `butnDisabled` variable continuously checks for required form fields and returns true or false.

It's returning different boolean values but `@Input` is not capturing them.

I tried like this:

```
@Input('butnDisabled')
  set butnDisabled(value: any) {
    this.disable = value;
  }
```

Can anyone suggest a way to get continuous input using the `@Input` tag?

Comment: Just use `@Input() set butnDisabled(val) {//}`

Answer (score 1):

Don't add any parameters to the input decorator, use it like:

```
@Input() set butnDisabled(value: any) {
    this.disable = value;
}
```

Comment: @saikrishna I would need some more detail, would be able to replicate your issue here -> https://stackblitz.com ?

Comment: i added the piece of code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rlq8vf here.. now i  want to write a method in app.component.ts to let the hello component know the status of each button whether it's disabled or not

Comment: may be i should add code for that also.. i will add it

Comment: @saikrishna but hello component is already aware of the state of buttons that is why you only have one enabled button, the texts on the button, etc. I didn't get your requirement

Comment: @saikrishna why have you added another method? That is basically reversing the disabled state. But still this is not your question, is it? if you add a `console.log(val)` under the `set disabl(val) {}` , you should see logs